# Register Twig extensions and cache directory

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.4

I have problems with adding Twig extensions.

I have Bundle controllers extending custom BaseController class:

```
class DefaultController extends BaseController
```

And there's my BaseController class (only part of it).

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

public function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    parent::setContainer($container);
    $this->onContainerSet();
}

public function onContainerSet()
{
  // many other tasks

    $this->get('twig')->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_StringLoader());

    $this->get('twig.loader')->addPath('../app');

    $function = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('stars', function ($number, $maximum_stars = 5) {
        $this->get('twig')->addGlobal('star_number',sprintf("%.1f",$number));
        $this->get('twig')->addGlobal('star_max',$maximum_stars);

        $full_stars = floor($number);
        $half_stars = ($number - $full_stars) * 2;
        $empty_stars = $maximum_stars - $full_stars - $half_stars;

        $this->get('twig')->addGlobal('full_stars_number',$full_stars);
        $this->get('twig')->addGlobal('half_stars_number',$half_stars);
        $this->get('twig')->addGlobal('empty_stars_number',$empty_stars);


        echo $this->renderView(
            'views/stars.html.twig'
        );;
    });


    $function2 = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('inurl', function ($anchor, $code) {
        echo '<a href="'.$this->internalLinks[$code].'">'.$anchor."</a>";

    });


    $this->get('twig')->addFunction($function);
    $this->get('twig')->addFunction($function2);

   }
}
```

The problem:

When I clear cache directory I have first message:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Unable to register
>   extension "string_loader" as extensions have already been
>   initialized." at ...\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php line
>   660 Context: {"exception":"Object(LogicException)"}

But when I reload page (cache folder is already created) it works fine (no exception).

However if I comment line:

```
// $this->get('twig')->addExtension(new \Twig_Extension_StringLoader());
```

and clear cache directory I have exception:

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: "Unable to add
>   function "stars" as extensions have already been initialized." at
>   ...\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php line 946 Context:
>   {"exception":"Object(LogicException)"}

So it seems that when cache directory doesn't exist from some reason adding any Twig extensions doesn't work (extensions have already been initialized) as I would like but when cache directory is already created everything works fine.

**Question** - how to solve it in the simplest way?

Comment: Why won't you load extension via service?

Comment: I could try but I don't know how to do this. I tried with Twig_Extension_StringLoader a moment ago but it didn't work

Comment: Why would you register twig extension in controller? Docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: First I don't know how to enable Twig_Extension_StringLoader that way. And another issue I don't know how to pass extra data to Estension as I have $this->internalLinks in $function2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your class in `YourBundle\Twig`

```
class YourExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    protected $router;

    function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('my_filter', [$this, 'myFilter'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function myFilter(User $user)
    {
        return 'FILTERED: ' . $user->getName();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_filter_extension';
    }

}
```

Then, register your extension as a service: ( in this case I inject `router` as an argument )

```
yourbundle.twig.my_filter_extension:
    class: Acme\YourBundle\Twig\YourExtension
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

If you want to enable `Twig_Extension_StringLoader`, add to your services:

```
yourbundle.twig.extension.loader:
    class: Twig_Extension_StringLoader
    tags:
        - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

`Twig_Extension_StringLoader` is not loaded by default.

Comment: Ok, but those function I use I need them in all bundles. And I don't know how to pass them $this->internalLinks and how to register \Twig_Extension_StringLoader() as this extension is built in

Comment: They will be available in all your templates, all bundles ;)

Comment: But I still don't know how to enable Twig_Extension_StringLoader extension to make it work

Comment: Ok, thanks. It helped me a lot. But the last thing - how to pass internalLinks that are property of BaseController to Twig Extension ? It's not a constant but variable

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Define your `DefaultController` [as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html), then pass this service as an `argument` of your extention service

Comment: should I do it for every controller that will finally use this Twig_Extension ? I solve this issue maybe not the best way simple using addGlobal to give this parameter to Twig Extension as in my answer above

Comment: IMO you have to declare your `DefaultController` as a service, but I think there's a better option: Create new service `InternalLinksService` then you can inject your `InternalLinksService` into other services or use it in all controllers as follows: `$this->get('your_bundle.internal_links')->yourMethod()`

Answer (score 2):

What I finally did to achieve result (maybe someone will have similar problem in the future):

In config.yml I've added:

```
services:
    yourbundle.twig.extension.loader:
        class: Twig_Extension_StringLoader
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.extension' }

    yourbundle.twig.stars_extension:
        class: Mnab\Twig\Stars
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.extension' }

    yourbundle.twig.inurl_extension:
        class: Mnab\Twig\InternalUrl
        tags:
            - { name: 'twig.extension' }
```

in my BaseController I only left from question code:

```
    $this->get('twig.loader')->addPath('../app');
```

but also added:

```
    $this->get('twig')->addGlobal('internal_links',$this->internalLinks);
```

to use it in Twig extension

And I've create 2 classes:

```
<?php
//InternalUrl.php
namespace Mnab\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class InternalUrl extends \Twig_Extension {


    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('inurl', array($this, 'inUrlFunction'), array('needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }


    public function inUrlFunction(\Twig_Environment $env, $anchor, $code)
    {
        return '<a href="'.$env->getGlobals()['internal_links'][$code].'">'.$anchor."</a>";
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'inurl_extension';
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php
// Stars.php

namespace Mnab\Twig;


class Stars extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('stars', array($this, 'starsFunction'), array('needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function starsFunction(\Twig_Environment $env, $number, $maximum_stars = 5)
    {


        $env->addGlobal('star_number',sprintf("%.1f",$number));
        $env->addGlobal('star_max',$maximum_stars);

        $full_stars = floor($number);
        $half_stars = ($number - $full_stars) * 2;
        $empty_stars = $maximum_stars - $full_stars - $half_stars;

        $env->addGlobal('full_stars_number',$full_stars);
        $env->addGlobal('half_stars_number',$half_stars);
        $env->addGlobal('empty_stars_number',$empty_stars);


        return $env->render(
            'views/stars.html.twig'
        );

    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'stars_extension';
    }
}
```

Now it seems to work regardless of cache is created or not. So it seems to better register services when you want to use Twig Extensions than registering Extensions in Controller.